# vscode linters underlines entire class

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylint

I'm using vscode in two different environments - a cloud based VM (using remote-ssh) and a docker container (using remote-container).
I have pylint set up on both.

For some reason, when the linter finds and issue on the VM it underlines the entire scope of that issue. For example if I have a class with an issue, the entire class would be underlined.

On the docker environment however only the first letter of the class is underlined. This is much better.

I tried to understand where the difference comes from... went through the settings.json file of both environments and both workspaces but I can't seem to find any difference.

Anyone have any idea what setting affects this?

In the image below, the top code is from the VM, the bottom is from the docker

[image]

Comment: there is an issue with pylint, use a previous version until this is fixed, search SO for a similar question a few days ago

Comment: amazing! downgraded from 2.12.2 to 2.12.1 and now it works...
weird thing is, I have 2.12.2 on my docker container and there the issue doesn't exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an open issue in pylint regarding this : https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/5466. It's scheduled to be in 2.13.0. Downgrading to 2.12.1 solve the issue but also remove other end of line end of column information introduced in https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/5336

Answer (score 0):

downgrading from pylint==2.12.2 to pylint==2.12.1 seems to have solved the issue